# just a clarification on dual boot OS usage

Tags: hadoop

im using a dual boot system that has windows 8 -64 bit version and ubuntu 13.04 -32 bit version. i'm tryng to install Hadoop frame work on my system.i'm getting trouble in installing hadoop. **Does the mixed version of a 32 bit and 64 bit effect hadoop installation?**

Comment: On which platform you are installing hadoop? If ubuntu, avoid using ntfs hard drives. Put hadoop files on an ext4 partition.

Comment: What is the actual error message that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean mixed in the sense that you are using 64-bit windows and 32-bit Linux, then no. Those aren't really mixed at all. Neither OS is aware of the other. I assume you are installing Hadoop on Linux and not on Windows, right? Personally I think installing Hadoop on 32-bit Linux is a little silly since the whole point of Hadoop is to process big data, so you probably want machines with more than 4GB of RAM.

Just remember that whatever OS you are installing Hadoop on, you should match the architecture of both the software and the JVM.